# Javascript Variable Function (Twig)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig, components, uniqueidentifier

My default.htm (to set unique id)

```
{ % set uid = __SELF__.id % }

<div id="tab" name="{{uid}}" class="my-tab draggable-tab ui-draggable">
    <img id="tab-avatar" alt="Virtual agent avatar" style="height:50px; width:50px" src="{{__SELF__.avatarImage}}">
    <div id="tab-minimize">
        <div id="tab-label"></div>
        <div id="tab-expand" name="{{uid}}" class="tab-expand tab-btn"></div>
        <div id="tab-close" name="{{uid}}" class="tab-close tab-btn" onclick="tabClose()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function tabClose(){      
var uid = document.getElementsByName("name");
    $(this).click(function() { 
        $("#tab").addClass("hidden");  //<--- how to put the uid in?
    });
}
```

---

JS

```
var tab_{{uid}} = function tabClose(){
                       $("#tab-close").click(function() {        
                           $("#tab").addClass("hidden");
                       });
                  }
```

Can someone show me how to use twig in JavaScript?

How to set unique id for each component so that when I duplicate the component it will not have any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call server variable (twig) in client program (javascript).

You must write the twig variable in your html code for javascript catch it.

For example, tout can put it in data attribute.

```
<div id="tab-close" data-uniqid={{uid}} >
```

And in your js

```
var uid = $("#tab-close").data('uniqid');
```

or with your update

```
var uid = $("#tab").attr('name');
```

**UPDATE**

For your problem, I think You don't need Twig variable in your js, this variable is here to have uniq Id in your html code.

So, try this:

```
<div id="tab{{__SELF__.id}}" class="my-tab draggable-tab ui-draggable">
    <img id="tab-avatar{{__SELF__.id}}" alt="Virtual agent avatar" style="height:50px; width:50px" src="{{__SELF__.avatarImage}}">
    <div id="tab-minimize{{__SELF__.id}}">
        <div id="tab-label{{__SELF__.id}}"></div>
        <div id="tab-expand{{__SELF__.id}}" class="tab-expand tab-btn"></div>
        <div id="tab-close{{__SELF__.id}}" class="tab-close tab-btn" onclick="tabClose()"></div>
</div>
```

And in your js

```
 $(".tab-close").click(function() {        
     $(this).closest(".my-tab").addClass("hidden");
 });
```

Comment: ohhh and how can I use the uid variable in my javascript function? Now I have two tabs(tabs which are duplicated), both have the same class name, id, etc. The only diff is they have their own unique name (<div id="tab" name={{uid}} > ). so if I put [ var uid = $("#tab").attr('name'); ]
How to close the tab when I press the close button of the specific tab?
Meaning I want to click tab 1 close button to close tab 1 and click tab 2 close button to close tab 2.

Comment: You're welcome. The important is that you understand difference between server variable and client variable. :)

Comment: btw can I change it visibility by this way ( $(this).closest(".cb-window").css("visibility", "visible"); ) /( $(this).closest(".cb-window").css("visibility", "hidden")?

Comment: hmm if I have more than one class do I have to list out all in order to use the .css("visiblility","hidden")?